# PHP обновление и запись в БД

Tags: php, sql

Коллеги, добрый день, заранее прошу прощенье за смуту, я больше фронтовик, но работа вынуждает и в бэкэнде писать.

Прошу помочь с проблемой или дать направление, Ajax и Comet мне не подходит, нет возможности нагружать сервер, интуитивно чувствую, что решение должно быть простым, заранее всех благодарю.

Итак, проблема:

На странице,  к примеру, page.php имеется стандартный SQL подсчет количества срок в Таблице №1 с одновременной записью суммы подсчета в Таблицу №2, теперь когда в Таблице №1 увеличивается количество строк отправляемое со всем с другой страницы, открытой клиентом, подсчет и запись в Таблицу №2 без обновления страницы page.php не происходит. Так вот как прописать на стороне клиента или как-то по иному обновление page.php если клиент в нее не входит и не войдет или есть ли другие решения? 
Просто хотелось, чтобы код в page.php был на стороне сервера и не загружался на стороне клиента.

Comment: Уточню. Есть две базы. вы хотите сделать денормализацию. Чтоб в БД2 хранилось всегда актуальное значение количества строк находящихся в БД1? Базы разные или база одна, но две схемы?

Comment: @Ninazu, Спасибо за уточнение. Мною некорректно указано, извините, всего база данных одна, а таблицы две. В одну таблицу №1 записывается, грубо говоря, действия клиентов (к примеру, клик) в другую №2 записывается сумма всех этих кликов. Данная круговерть обусловлена созданием диаграмм посредствам Google charts. Заказчик просит красивую аналитику. Код SQL по суммированию строк записан на странице page.php в которую клиент так и не попадает и не попадет. А по сему обновиться эта страница не может соответственно изменения в таблице №1 код SQLне видит, как результат диаграмма некорректная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Привел общие способы решения вашей проблемы, но здесь все зависит от архитектуры используемой у Вас и требований к актуальности данных.**

---

Приведу аналогию, есть магазин который продает товары и проданные товары записываются в базу, но есть менеджер который хочет знать, на какую сумму были проданы товары, для этого у него есть несколько путей решения:

- Запускать подсчет каждые n-времени (ему без разницы, что в эту минуту цифра не совсем точна)
- Получать сообщение о проданном товаре и самостоятельно запускать подсчет проданных товаров
- При добавлении товара сразу агрегировать статистику в автоматическом режиме через различные способы:

  1. Отправка данных или задачи на удаленный сервер для запуска автоматического подсчета.
  2. Агрегация на стороне программы, которая выполняет добавление (при больших данных будет тормозить, если это не просто атомарная операция)

---

### Подсчет всех строк в базе для вывода

В вашем случае, наверное лучшее решение и простое решение, это выполнение скрипта подсчета (page.php) каждые 1-5 минут по CRON, если Вам не нужно знать точное в каждую секунду кол-во добавленных строк.

Второе решение, которое позволяет точно отсчитывать кол-во строк, это сделать на стороне скрипта, который добавляет данные в базу (если это единичная точка добавления), увеличение в каком-то кеше значения на кол-во добавленных строк и после чего вывод данного значения. Тут нужно немного продумать архитектуру, ведь строки еще могут удаляться и т.д. Можно также на таблицу повесить триггер, который бы при добавлении записи выполнял какую-то атомарную операцию по увеличению значения в другой таблице.

Так же, какой-то скрипт может от другого скрипта получать сообщение через  очередь и по получении сообщения выполнять действия связанные с подсчетом строк - это правда уже демонизация.

### Подсчет строк для определенного клиента

Далее, если ваша проблема заключается именно в подсчете не всех строк, а подсчете строк для клиента, здесь уже немного сложнее. Если база маленькая, то выполнение подсчета каждую минуту для всех не составит труда, но если база огромная, и Вам нужно считать для всех клиентов с группировкой, этот запрос может выполняться дольше и каждые 1-5 он может просто не исполняться, возможно здесь использовать подсчет по запросу.

Клиент обращается к скрипту постоянно через сайт, но скрипт сохраняет данные всего 1 раз, после чего хранит значение в кеше на 5 минут, если клиент добавил какие-то данные их можно инвалидировать в кеше.

Comment: накопал еще такое решение: хранить в бд запись (дату выполнения) ... если дата не сегодняшний день, то обновляем запись, выполняем скрипт. Как вам такое решение?

Comment: @KBMira Можете добавить как дополнительное условие в скрипт, но использовать CRON в вашем случае, мне кажется это самое оптимальное по времени и скорости решение. Запускайте с тем интервалом, с которым важна точность данных.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответы. Вчера экспериментировал и вот, что получилось: на страницу пользователя index.php добавил include_once‘page.php’, но прежде вручную в админки увеличил число строк таблицы, обновил index.php и… о чудо … page.php все просуммировало и обновила запись в таблице 2. Видимо необходимо изучать азы пхп.